# exploding when returned to result() failed

Tags: php, explode, codeigniter-3

Here am using the function explode function for exploding datas from datable and explode works only when `row()` given not getting when returned to `result()`.
here is my table

```
id  name                       tools_names                                quantity  

9   T20            T20A,T20B,T20C,T20D,T20E,T20F,T20G,T20H,T20I,T20J        10  
10  krone tool     krone toolA,krone toolB,krone toolC,krone toolD,kr...     5
```

Here is my Control

```
    $data['tools']=$this->Tools_model->view_available_tools();
    $data['toolss'] = explode(',',$data['tools']->tools_names);
    $data['toolss'] = array_values($data['toolss']);
    //return $data['toolss'];
    var_dump($data['toolss']);
```

here is my model

```
public function view_available_tools()
{
    $this->db->order_by('id','desc');
    $query=$this->db->get('tools');
    return $query->result();
}
```

when I  returned  the first rows tools_names values is coming but I want  to get all tools_names of all the rows . This  is not coming please help me to solve this issue.

my view looks like this

```
<div class="form-group">
        <label for="tools" class="control-label">Tools:</label>
        <select name="tools[]" class="form-control" multiple="multiple" required>
        <option value="">please select</option>
        <?php foreach($toolss as $row){?>

        <option value="<?php echo $row;?>"><?php echo $row;?></option>
        <?php }?>
        </select>
      </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must use return `$query->result_array();` or equivalent

```
public function view_available_tools()
{
    $this->db->order_by('id','desc');
    $this->db->where('status',1);
    $query=$this->db->get('tools');
    return $query->result_array(); 
}
```

**EDIT:**

Please update your controller too

```
$data['tools']=$this->Tools_model->view_available_tools();
foreach ($data['tools'] as $key=>$val) {
    $data['toolss'][] = explode(',',$val['tools_names']);
}
$data['toolss'] = array_values($data['toolss']);  
var_dump($data['toolss']);
```

**Edit2:**

View Update,

```
<div class="form-group">
        <label for="tools" class="control-label">Tools:</label>
        <select name="tools[]" class="form-control" multiple="multiple" required>
        <option value="">please select</option>
        <?php foreach($toolss as $key=>$val){
               foreach ($val as $key2=>$val2){
        ?>

        <option value="<?php echo $val2;?>"><?php echo $val2;?></option>
        <?php 
           }
         } ?>
        </select>
      </div>
```

Comment: i had added my view there please have a look

Comment: `notice message:array to string conversion`

Comment: `A PHP Error was encountered Severity: Notice Message: Array to string conversion Filename: views/add_user_tools.php Line Number: 79 Backtrace: File: C:\wamp64\www\rsspectra\application\modules\Tools\views\add_user_tools`

Comment: I have updated the answer with view part. You have explode more about array manipulation. Good Luck!

Comment: You need to use nested `foreach` statement in the view since `$toolss` is multi dimensional array. View portion updated in the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Try below code ::-

```
<?php
foreach ($data['tools']->tools_names as $tools_key => $tools_val) {
    $data['toolss'][] = explode(',', $tools_val);
}
$data['toolss'] = call_user_func_array('array_merge', array_values($data['toolss']));
var_dump($data['toolss']);
?>
```